# R - Read multiple Variable/Objects in a loop

Tags: r, loops

Is it possible to read multiple user-defined objects/variable in a loop in R?
I have more than 50 variables and i have to write same code over and over again to execute all the variables.

If it is possible to use the loop to read the objects, it would help me a lot.

Thank you in advance. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Question is too broad. Please provide reproducible data and the intended output for more constructive replies.

Comment: What could be the reproducible data for this? I have many variables in my R environment and each variables have more than 20 columns. I have to do some calculations and all. For that i have to write the same code for 50 times or more, with only the changes made in the variable name. Can you read one variable at a time and do the calculation? @AdamQuek

Comment: As a generic steps: (i) create list of objects (each corresponding to one data.frame/vector/object in the R environment); (ii) use loop or apply with function `get(x)` to implement calculations. There are too many ways to go after that however...

Comment: Okay I will try that. Thank you @AdamQuek

Comment: put in an example below with a generic `colSums` for 10 data.frame. Obviously not what you wanted, but without knowing what calculation or help you needed, can't really provide more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume I have 10 iris data sets named as a.01 to a.10:

```
for(i in 1:10) assign(sprintf("a.%02d", i), iris)
```

(i) create list of objects:

```
list_of_objects <- grep("a[.]", ls(), value=T)
```

(ii) calculate colSums for each:

```
lapply(list_of_objects, function(x) colSums(get(x)[-5])) # remove column 5 since iris[,5] == iris$Species (non-numeric)
```

Comment: This is not what i needed but i might use it in some other way. thank you.

Comment: How can i use this same function to apply `as.POSIXct` to the first column of all files.

Comment: Put up a new question, with reproducible data, to describe what is it you require more clearly.

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873160/how-to-use-loop-to-apply-as-posxict-to-a-column-of-multiple-files