# How to use loop to apply as.POSXIct to a column of multiple files

Tags: r

This is a code i have been using so far to apply `as.POSIXct` for a `date_time` column of multiple files. If I can do this in a loop it would make my life much easier. The date and time are not formatted for any of the file, so the first step i have to do is to format the `date_time` column and then carry out other calculations for each files.
This is the code I have been using so far.

```
> set(wd)
> files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
> for(i in 1:length(files)) {
  assign(sprintf("a.%02d", i), read.csv(files[i], header=T))
  }
> a.01[,1] <- as.POSIXct(a.01[,1], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%S")
> a.02[,1] <- as.POSIXct(a.02[,1], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%S")
> a.03[,1] <- as.POSIXct(a.03[,1], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%S")
> a.04[,1] <- as.POSIXct(a.04[,1], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%S")
> a.05[,1] <- as.POSIXct(a.05[,1], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%S")
> a.06[,1] <- as.POSIXct(a.06[,1], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%S")
............................................................
and so on.
```

My sample data looks something like this. Each files consists of more than 3000 rows and multiple column. The following structure shows only the first 10 rows of one of the file, all other files are of same format.

```
> dput(head(a.01, n=10))
structure(list(date_time = structure(c(-61759604476, -61759593676, 
-61759582876, -61759572076, -61759561276, -61759550476, -61759539676, 
-61759528876, -61759518076, -61759507276), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), V1 = c(1002, 1002, 1002, 
1001, 1000, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004), V2 = c(2.228, 
0.7123, 2.67, 4.378, 4.102, 3.782, 1.669, 1.356, 0.3223, 0.2053
), V3 = c(34.48, 8.455, 247.4, 259.8, 276, 333.7, 289.4, 
324, 2.45, 306.9), V4 = c(32.23, 28.6, 31.04, 29.73, 35.24, 
41.17, 37.49, 38.7, 40.8, 36.45), V5 = c(17.55, 
18.55, 21.75, 23.65, 22.15, 19.65, 19.05, 17.25, 16.45, 17.35
)), .Names = c("Date", "V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data looks something like this and all other files are of similar pattern with unformatted date and time.

```
> head(a.01, n=5)
   date_time          V1     V2       V3       V4       V5
1  12-12-01 00:00:00  1002   2.2280   34.480   32.23    17.55
2  12-12-01 03:00:00  1002   0.7123   8.455    28.60    18.55
3  12-12-01 06:00:00  1002   2.6700   247.400  31.04    21.75
4  12-12-01 09:00:00  1001   4.3780   259.800  29.73    23.65
5  12-12-01 12:00:00  1000   4.1020   276.000  35.24    22.15
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should read into a list, rather than into similarly-named variables.  Then looping through the list is very easy.

Comment: .Names = c("Date", "V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V3" ) replace column name V3 to V5 at the end

Answer (score 2):

Read into a list, and the problem goes away:

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
a <- lapply(files, function(f) {
  x <- read.csv(f)
  x[,1] = as.POSIXct(x[,1], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%S")
  x
}
names(a) <- files
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dates are being read incorrectly. You have `"%m/%d/%Y"` as your Date format string and it apparently should be: `"%m/%d/%y"`. A more definitive answer would be possible if you posted the top of the file as text rather than what you R code has created. I'm getting this as the output of you structure:

```
                  Date   V1     V2      V3    V4    V3
1  0012-11-30 10:25:46 1002 2.2280  34.480 32.23 17.55
2  0012-11-30 13:25:46 1002 0.7123   8.455 28.60 18.55
```

So your 'years' are being interpreted as 12 years since the beginning of the "Common Era".

Comment: I have posted the `head` of my original file.

Comment: The value returned by `head` cannot be the text you were reading with `read.csv` .... since it has no commas.